# How do I interpret data from a 2x2 experiment with a floor effect that causes it to lack any variation in one cell?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, interpretation, zero-inflation

I have performed a 2x2 experiment to measure the effects of two genetic factors on the occurrence and size of a rare birth defect. When an individual has the defect, we can measure its size (size is a continuous value greater than zero, with no upper bound.)

Here is some size data similar to what we're seeing. When an individual doesn't have a defect it's shown as a 0 on the plot (So this is a case of severely zero-inflated data):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJcjT.png]

I would like to:

1. Determine whether there are differences in the incidence of defects between the four groups.
2. Determine whether there are differences in the size of the defects that do occur.

Ideally, I would like to demonstrate an interaction (or lack thereof) between the two factors.

For incidence (1)
I have binned these values into a very simple system such as the following:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+--------+
| Condition |  Gene 1   |  Gene 2   | Normal | Mild | Severe |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+--------+
| A         | Low Risk  | Low Risk  |      9 |    0 |      0 |
| B         | Low Risk  | High Risk |      5 |    5 |      1 |
| C         | High Risk | Low Risk  |      6 |   10 |      0 |
| D         | High Risk | High Risk |      1 |    5 |     16 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+--------+
```

and then I can perform Fisher's exact test between the relevant conditions: A vs B, A vs C, A vs D, B vs D, and C vs D. This works fine but it doesn't assess an interaction between the factors.

For defect size (2) I initially wanted to do a two-way ANOVA (to assess interaction), but I don't think it's possible. Most individuals don't have a defect except in the most severe situation, thus I end up with zero-inflated data set. Not only that, in the Low-Low category there's no variation at all! If I drop all the zero values (which makes sense - the absence of a defect is not really the same thing as a defect of even negligible size) then I'm left with nothing at all in my low-low condition. I can make comparisons between the groups with rank-sum data, but only if I drop all the zeroes, otherwise the test is inappropriate. When I do this, I destroy 75% of my sample size (100% in the low-low case)

Is there a more efficient way to look at this data?

Comment: Three ideas: (1) How about comparing two groups (aka conditions) at a time, omitting the low-low group: gene 1 low risk vs gene 1 high risk (considering only the gene 2 high risk conditions), and gene 2 low risk vs gene 2 high risk (considering only the gene 1 high risk conditions)?  You will not be able to make a statement about interaction, but you knew that.

Comment: (2) I would not drop zero scores from any group that had non-zero scores.  The zero scores from those groups are telling you something.  (3) If you are using a non-parametric approach, perhaps the lack of variability among the (artificially compressed) zero scores is not as problematic. If the non-parametric test shows statistical significance with a floor effect, then I think it would show a greater statistical effect without the floor effect.

Comment: So, from what I understand, the floor effect will introduce a bias in rank-based tests, but biases in the direction of non-significance, basically it compromises power but won't cause type I errors.

Comment: Pairwise comparisons by Fisher's exact test are what I decided on for the categorical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-parametric, rank-based method to perform two-way ANOVAs with interactions is a method proposed by Brunner, Dette, and Munk (1997), which improves on the Kruskal- Wallis test
(for details, see Wilcox, 2010). This method should be able to deal with all-zero cells.

It can be performed using the `bdm2way` function from the `WRS` package for `R`.

---

Brunner, E., Domhof, S., & Langer, F. (2002). Nonparametric analysis of longitudinal data in factorial experiments. New York: Wiley.

Wilcox, R. R. (2010). Fundamentals of modern statistical methods: Substantially improving power and accuracy. Springer Verlag.

Comment: I will do some reading about these tests. Thanks for the references.

Comment: This has worked out very well. The `asbio` package for R also includes the similar `BDM.2way` function that I ended up using.